# cross tabulating two lists of binary columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on a shiny application that allows users to cross tabulate different groups in the data against each other. My challenge is that some of the variables in my data are classified by single columns (nice and mutually exclusive and can be included in a group_by easily) and others are made up of multiple binary columns with some degree of overlap. So in the shiny app, I have the option "Users", but that refers to the columns "A Users", "B users" etc.

Now, having both my row and columns of my cross tabulation as the single column style groups is nice and simple (example for reference)

```
data <- data.frame(Gender = sample(x=1:2, size=100, replace = T), Age = sample(x=1:3, size=100, replace = T),
                   A.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T), B.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T),
                   C.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T), D.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T),
                   E.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T), F.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T))

col_vars <- "Gender"
group_var <- "Age"

demog_vals <- data %>% group_by(!!sym(group_var), !!sym(col_vars)) %>%
          summarise(Total = n()) %>% spread(!!sym(col_vars), Total)
```

Having one of the row/column options as a single and the other as a list also wasn't too bad

```
#function to apply in dplyr summarise_at 
countifx <- function(y, x) {sum(as.numeric(x) == y, na.rm=T) / (length(x) - sum(is.na(x)))}

col_vars <- "Gender"
row_vars <- c("A User", "B User", "C User")

        demog_vals <- data %>% 
          group_by(!!sym(col_vars)) %>% 
          #gsub to change spaces to "." to match dataframe names
          summarise_at(gsub(" ", ".", row_vars, fixed = T), list(Total =~ countifx(1,.))) %>% 
          gather(key, Total, -1) %>% 
          extract(key, c("Users", "measure"), "([A-z0-9\\.]*)_([A-z0-9]*)") %>% 
          spread(!!sym(col_vars), Total) %>% 
          select(-measure)

        demog_vals$Users <- gsub(".", " ", demog_vals$Users, fixed = T)
        demog_vals[, -1] <- sapply(demog_vals[,-1], function(x){paste0(round(x / sum(x) * 100, 1), "%")})
```

But I'm really struggling to get this to work for the situation where both the rows and columns are the combination of these multiple binary columns. The furthest I've got so far is

```
col_vars <- c("A User", "B User", "C User")
row_vars <- c("D User", "E User", "F User")

demog_vals <- data %>% group_by_at(vars((gsub(" ", ".", row_vars, fixed = T)))) %>% 
  summarise_at(gsub(" ", ".", col_vars, fixed = T), list(Total =~ countifx(1,.))) %>% 
  gather(key, Total, c(-1:-6)) %>% 
  extract(key, c("Users", "measure"), "([A-z0-9\\.]*)_([A-z0-9]*)") %>% 
  select(-measure)
```

However, this gives me every combination of the different levels of 1's and 0's across all of my different variable pairs - I'm just interested in the individual columns that I'm grouping by and not the interactions (i.e. I've got 24 rows and want 3, so (0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,1) etc. when I just want (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1) but not the ones that I'd get from filtering what I get from the above code - if that makes any sense...

I may be wildly over-complicating this, but I've been staring at it for over a long time now and have run out of ideas to google. Any help would be massively appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get something that gives me the output I need by simplifying the pipeline and wrapping it inside of a for loop

```
#create data
data <- data.frame(Gender = sample(x=1:2, size=100, replace = T), Age = sample(x=1:3, size=100, replace = T),
                   A.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T), B.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T),
                   C.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T), D.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T),
                   E.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T), F.User = sample(x=0:1, size=100, replace = T))

#specify lists of columns to use
col_vars <- c("A User", "B User", "C User")
row_vars <- c("D User", "E User", "F User")

#define custom function to use in summarise step
countifx <- function(y, x) {sum(as.numeric(x) == y, na.rm=T) / (length(x) - sum(is.na(x)))}

#create empty dataframe
demog_vals <- data.frame()

#loop for each item in row_vars list
for (i in 1:length(row_vars)){
  #specify row item
  group_var <- row_vars[i]
  #group and summarise data
  out <- data %>% group_by(!!sym(gsub(" ", ".", group_var, fixed = T))) %>% 
  summarise_at(gsub(" ", ".", col_vars, fixed = T), list(Total =~ countifx(1,.))) %>% 
  filter(!!sym((gsub(" ", ".", group_var, fixed = T)) == 1) %>%
  gather(key, Total, -1) %>% 
  extract(key, c("Users", "measure"), "([A-z0-9\\.]*)_([A-z0-9]*)") %>% 
  select(-measure)
  #coerce output to data frame
  out <- as.data.frame(out)

  out[, 1] <- group_var
  colnames(out) <- c("col user", "row user", "Total")

  #if data frame empty then set to out, otherwise append
  if (i == 1){
    demog_vals <- out
  } else {
    demog_vals <- bind_rows(demog_vals, out)
  }

}
#spread the column variables out
demog_vals <- demog_vals %>% spread('Users', Total)
```

I'm not sure this is the most elegant or efficient solution, but in practice, the longest list I will be looping over has 15 elements, so for now it should do the job, but I'd be interested to know if anyone has a better option